# Ensure BLE scanner android application always run in background

Tags: java, android, service, bluetooth

I have made an Bluetooth Low Energy Scanner android app and I would like it to always scan at the background. 
My case now is when user open the application, it will start scanning but once I clear the task manager of the phone the application will stop scanning.

I would like the application to always scan all the time, even when the user clears the task manager.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLE scanning doesn't use much power at all. Not particularly more than having Wi-Fi enabled. As described in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder.html#setScanMode(int), you can choose between SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER, SCAN_MODE_BALANCED or SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY. Note however that scanning with highest duty (SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY) may have bad effects on Wi-Fi throughput since it occupies the radio.

To make sure the app stays alive even though Activities have shut down, you can have a foreground service running in your process (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). Note that with some chinese phones (Xiaomi, Oppo etc.) the user also needs to go into System settings and enable background execution for your app.

Comment: Thank you very much! My issue is that I'm using Xiaomi phone. The way to change is Settings > Permissions>Autostart> Choose the app you want to 'autostart'.

Answer (score -3):

Why do you need scan all the time? it will waste so mush power.
Android task manager can kill application and application's service.
I think it can not be achieved.

Comment: A few things to improve with this answer. It doesn't matter _why_ the OP is trying to scan in the background (I can think of many reasons somebody would want to). Also, it doesn't waste that much power if you do it correctly. And finally, it can be achieved.